# Why is my react router switch not detecting the auth state change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently I have the following react router

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
          {/* It should display the register page if the isAuthenticated state is true */}
    <Route exact path="/register" render={(props) => ((this.state.isAuthenticated) ? <RegisterPage />  : <NewLandingPage {...props} /> )} />
    <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => <LoginPage />} />

    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

In my App.js

And then in the constructor of my App.js I have the following states, and authservice call

```
this.state = {
        isAuthenticated: false
    }

    isAuthenticated().then((result) => {
        if (result == true) {
            this.state.isAuthenticated = true;
            console.log("its true authenticated");
            console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated);
            console.log("----")
        } else {
            this.state.isAuthenticated = false;
            console.log("its false not autheticated");
            console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated);
            console.log("----")
        }
    });
```

By default, my isAuthenticated state is false. So i wouldnt be able to display "/register" if I hadnt an auth service.

But I have implemented an isAuthenticated() to make the app.js check if theres a valid user. It actually displays the desired data. For example, if im autheticated, the result would be true, and I would receive the following in my console.

```
console.log("its true authenticated");
console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated); //true
```

But seems that the browserrouter is not taking into effect the isAuthenticated() method, and is relying solely in the default value, which is false, so It will always hide my register page will never be displayed besides me having an authservice there

```
this.state = {
    isAuthenticated: false
}
```

Any idea of why is my browser not detecting the states change?

**EDIT:**

isAuthenticated() function by request

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

export default function isAuthenticated(){
    var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');

    return axios({ method: 'post', url: 'http://localhost:3003/verify', headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accesstoken}` } })
        .then(function (response) {
             if(response.data.status === "valid"){
                 console.log("service valid")
                 return true;
             }else{
                 console.log("service invalid")
                 return false;
             }
        });
}
```

Comment: `isAuthenticated()` can you share the content of this function? if this is the property `isAthenticated` in the state, you shouldn't call this by this way, always change the state with setState function like: `this.setState({ isAthenticated: true})`

Comment: Try this isAuthenticated().then((result) => { this.setState({isAthenticated: result})})

Comment: @OnerT.it actually wokrs this way, but I can see the newlandingpage for a brief second before the switch is completly loaded

Comment: @OnerT. edited my previous comment, I misstyped something

Comment: @mouchin777 take a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the state with redux(for example with an action you bring the component from actions in redux, and it sets new state in the reducer), it will effect after the component mount, there is a way to render the component(If the props have changed) and get the new state status, with ComponentDidUpdate method:

So the actions effect the global state(in reducer), and you bring this state to your component. ComponentDidUpdate will take a look and when the state you bring with the props has changed, it will update the component and allow you to execute setState

```
ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated !== prevProps.isAuthenticated) {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated:true
      });
     // I suppose you call the state from the reducer by this.props.isAuthenticated
    }
  }
```

Also for checking the authentication state, I am using an auth.js util like this, it gets the authenticated state from reducer,  makes a redirect to login page instead of the component, if authenticated is false:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      authenticated === true ? (
        <Redirect to="/user" />
      ) : (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
    }
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authenticated: state.user.authenticated
});

AuthRoute.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.object
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthRoute);
```

so in my app.js, I can check the auth state and redirect if necessary:

```
        import AuthRoute from "./util/AuthRoute.js";

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/user" component={home} />
          <AuthRoute exact path="/login" component={userLogin} />
          <AuthRoute exact path="/signup" component={userSignup} />
          <Route exact path="/ticketList" component={ticketList} />
        </Switch>
```

Comment: your authRoute.js , where does it get the response from the user being or not authenticated? Also, trying to test it I receive an error like ```Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(AuthRoute)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(AuthRoute) in connect options.``` . Also ComponentDidUpdate ,i supposed to be in each component, or in the app.js main component?

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authenticated: state.user.authenticated
});` it is from the authenticated store in the reducer by redux. I bring and use it by `mapStateToProps` which sets the state of the reducer to the component's props like `this.props.authenticated`

Comment: You are using redux for state-management right? You should create an action and a reducer for each action js, this will provide a global state and you can use it in an individual component simply set it to components' props by mapStateToProps:
https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: No I wasnt, but I will check it

Comment: `ComponentDidUpdate` you can use it any Class-based component, it is one of the lifecyle methods of React, check it here: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class Also if you are new to React I can recommend you this tutorial, I also started with it and it covers all topics from scratch about react and redux: https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the issue is that the authentication code is in your constructor which gets called once. You might want to try it a slightly different way. Create a const (outside your class) to hold the switchable component content:

```
export const RegisterOrLandingPage = () => {
  if (isAuthenticated()) {
    return <RegisterPage />;
  }
  return <NewLandingPage />;
}
```

Your *isAuthenticated()* code should ideally be in a **function** too, rather than sat in the constructor or used as a state, and abstracted out to its own component (i.e., callable from anywhere, usable by anyone).

Then your route can be slightly different:

```
<Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterOrLandingPage} />
```